# Adding XLS file in a sheet next to the existing sheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which populates a graph and adds two sheets to the workbook. How can i add a sheet which pulls the data from an excel file from a specific folder and adds the excel file to a sheet preceding the other two sheets?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim files(1 To 20) As String
    Dim numOfFiles As Integer
    Dim chartName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFile1 As String
    Dim strChart As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer


    strPath = "C:\PortableRvR\report\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    i = 1
    Do While strFile <> ""
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strPath & strFile, _
                Destination:=.Range("A1"))
                .Parent.Name = Replace(strFile, ".csv", "")
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                files(i) = .Parent.Name
                i = i + 1
            End With
        End With
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    chartName = "Chart 8"
    For j = 1 To numOfFiles
        strFile = files(j)
        Sheets(strFile).Select
        Plot_y = Range("E1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Plot_x = Range("D1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        Sheets("Uplink VS attenuation").Select
        If j = 1 Then ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Activate

        With ActiveChart

            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "TxPower"
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Attenuation(dB)"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "TxPower(dBm)"
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 30 ' Constant value

        End With

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Name = strFile
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).XValues = Sheets(strFile).Range("D1:D" & Plot_x)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Values = Sheets(strFile).Range("E1:E" & Plot_y)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).MarkerStyle = -4142
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Smooth = False
    Next j

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = xlMillions
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasDisplayUnitLabel = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? If nothing then you might want to press the magic button "F1" from Excel VBA to check what `Sheets.Add` does ;)

Comment: Ok. What is the problem that you are facing with the above code?

Comment: Now I remember this code :) It was working earlier right? The charts were getting generated after the csv is imported. So the only thing that you want is to move that sheet before `Sheets("Uplink VS attenuation")` ?

Comment: Yes i want to add a new excel file (tst.xls) from a folder (Ex: C:\test) and add this excel file before all the Sheets("Uplink VS attenuation")

Comment: I see what you want. Let me give you an example.

Comment: Hope your query is sorted now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add say Sheet1 from Sample.txt to Book2.xlsx, which has `Sheets("Uplink VS attenuation")`, you can use this sample code

Please amend it to suit your needs.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet

    '~~> This is the workbook which has the "Uplink VS attenuation" sheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Uplink VS attenuation")

    '~~> Open the relevant text file. Change as applicable
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Temp\Sample.txt", Origin:=437, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
    Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Set wbTemp = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets(1)

    '~~> Copy the relevant sheet before "Uplink VS attenuation"
    wsTemp.Copy Before:=ws

    '~~> Close text file without saving
    wbTemp.Close savechanges:=False

    '~~> Clean Up
    Set wb = Nothing: Set wbTemp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing: Set wsTemp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: I have not done any error handling. I am sure you can take care of it :)

HTH

Sid